# What is the JQL to see if a state transition was performed by the assignee?

Tags: jira

I have a state transition from REVIEW to DONE. If I want all the tickets where JeffB was the assignee and also marked the review as done, I can use this JQL:

```
assignee in (JeffB) and status changed to DONE by JeffB
```

I could also iterate through everyone in the group to stitch together a complete list of people who closed their own tickets.

Is there a way to get that whole list where `assignee == changed-to-DONE-person` without plugging the users in one by one?

This is a how-to question. There is no current bad behavior to document.

Answer (score 0):

Here list of all fields accessible in JQL:
https://support.atlassian.com/jira-service-management-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-fields/

Here list of all functions accessible in JQL:
https://support.atlassian.com/jira-service-management-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-functions/

Unfortunately there is no way to express in JQL who triggered transition to status.